# Is this equality between an integral and a series wrong?

Tags: probability-distributions, sequences-and-series, integration, schwartz-distributions

In [this paper (Maroun's PhD dissertation, 2013)](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/3jb5b2dr) at page 46 the following formula is given (apparently without a reference):

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{i a x^s+i b x^p} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(i b a^{\frac{1}{s}}\right)^n \exp \left(\frac{(i \pi ) (n p+1)}{2 s}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n p+1}{s}\right)}{n! a^{\frac{1}{s}} \left| s\right| }$$

Now I am trying to verify the formula. If I take $a=b=i/2$, $s=p=1$ the left hand side becomes $1$ while right hand side becomes $8/3$. Is there some error in the formula? Is this formula even well-known?

Comment: @Stefan Kohl I fixed the link, thanks for pointing.

Comment: A formula with parameters requires quantifiers on the parameters. It is possibly understood that the parameters are reals, or positive reals. I don't know about your specific formula.

Comment: related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277580/question-on-the-integral-int-infty-infty-ea-x4b-x3c-x2d-xf-d

Answer (score 4):

We may change the variables as $xa^{1/s}=t$, this proves that $a^{1/s}\cdot \int$ is a function of $ba^{-p/s}$, not of $ba^{1/s}$.

Comment: Should I understand it that there is a typo, and the formula should have $b a ^{-p/s}$ instead? Then the right hand side apparently diverges...

Comment: Well, following regularization it gives now correct result, but I expected the right hand side to converge where the left had side does.

Comment: But, if a and b have opposite signs $a=1 b=-1$, while $p=s$ the result should be $0$, which is still not the case.

Comment: @Anixx, it is very common that different expressions for the same thing have different regions of convergence... and of convergence in various senses, perhaps not pointwise...

Answer (score 3):

I am verifying that it is true that there is a typo. The corrected expression should be a change to the right hand side series term in parenthesis.

It should read,
$$
\left(iba^{-\frac{p}{s}}\right)^n.
$$
The original context was that the convergence is only in the sense of distributions.